# GCC compiler errors with "No such file or directory"

Tags: gcc, c, compiler

My Ubuntu version is 12.04 LTS. I have written some C programs. But there is a compiler-problem. I've googled and found that I need build-essential. So I download and installed it.

After installation, it worked well. But after maybe 3 hours, the problem happened again.

When I write:

```
gcc -o -std=c99 sort sort.c
```

The compiler complains:

```
gcc: error: sort: No such file or directory.
```

I have no idea now.

Comment: Keep in mind, the order of the files and optional args is important. Like the answer below says, `gcc -o sort sort.c` will not link, whereas `gcc sort.c -o sort` will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will fix your problem:

```
gcc -std=c99 sort.c -o sort
```

Your command was telling gcc to compile a file called sort, which didn't exist, hence the error message.  The -o flag needs to be followed by the output name, but your line it was followed by -std=c99 which is not correct.

Comment: thanks! so it works. I've just wrote everything like examples. Now i know why. but still i want to know: is there someway to make `gcc -o -std=c99 sort sort.c` working?

Comment: Well, as said before, the -o option needs to specify the name of the output, so having the -std=c99 option immediately after -o is just not going to work.  How about gcc -o sort -std=c99 sort.c